# Getting highest available string in java

Tags: string, split, substring

I want to get the highest available string value in java how can i achieve this.

Example: hello jameswangfron

I want to get the highest string "jameswangfron"

String Text = request.getParameter("hello jameswangfron");

Please code example.

Comment: If you read [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_strings.htm) you might be able to do it on your own.

Comment: I found that tutorial in less than five seconds.  Please research before posting.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response this tutorial not helping me,i just want to take the highest string,any thig like (subtring,split,slice) will help me?

Comment: For example String OutputText = request.getParameter("hello jameswangfron");      output should return       //OutputText = jameswangfron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class HelloWorld{
   public static void main(String []args){
      String text = "hello jameswangfron";
      String[] textArray = text.split(" ");
      String biggestString = "";
      for(int i=0; i<textArray.length; i++){
         if(i==0) {
            textArray[i].length();
            biggestString = textArray[i];
         } else {
            if(textArray[i].length()>textArray[i-1].length()){
               biggestString = textArray[i];
            }
         }
      }
   System.out.println("Biggest String : "+biggestString);
   }
}
```

And it shows the output as

```
Biggest String : jameswangfron
```

Comment: Excellent Naveen this is what i want and its working thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be easyer to understand

```
    public class HelloWorld {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(StringManipulator.getMaxLengthString("hello jameswangfron", " "));
    }
}

class StringManipulator{

public static String getMaxLengthString(String data, String separator){     
    String[] stringArray = data.split(separator);
    String toReturn = "";
    int maxLengthSoFar = 0;
    for (String string : stringArray) {
        if(string.length()>maxLengthSoFar){
            maxLengthSoFar = string.length();
            toReturn = string;
        }
    }
    return toReturn;
    }
}
```

But there is a catch. If you pay attention to split method from class String, you will find out that the spliter is actually a regex. For your code, i see that you want to separate the words (which means blank space). if you want an entire text to search, you have to pass a regex.

Here's a tip. If you want your words to be separated by " ", ".", "," (you get the ideea) then you should replace the " " from getMaxLengthString method with the following

```
    "[^a-zA-Z0-9]"
```

If you want digits to split up words, simply put

```
    "[^a-zA-Z]"
```

This tells us that we use the separators as anything that is NOT a lower case letter or upper case letter. (the ^ character means you don't want the characters you listed in your brackets [])

Here is another way of doing this

```
    "[^\\w]"
```

\w it actually means word characters. so if you negate this (with ^) you should be fine

Comment: i hope you got a better idea about splitting and regex